# CSS calc not working in firefox

Tags: css

I have the following CSS for an element, in chrome it works OK but in Firefox, height is always calculating as `height: -moz-calc(57%);`

```
#unity-webgl{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 43px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 43px);
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 43px);
}
```

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Firefox and Chrome no-longer require the `-moz-` and `-webkit-` prefixes, you can use naked `calc()`.

Comment: @Dai You might need to keep -webkit for older versions of safari which doesn't auto-update, or can't update (Corporate policy, OS restrictions, etc).  But there really isn't much of a reason for the -moz prefix on calc anymore.

Comment: You should probably order your vendor prefixes such that the prefix-less one is last such that it will always be evaluated last. See https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/

Comment: You might also try: `height: -moz-calc(100vh - 43px);` or `height: calc(100vh - 43px);` which solves a number of issues when the parent container height isn't set.

Comment: If you are using an older version than 4.0 of Mozilla, you don't need to add the prefix, as you can see in Developer Mozilla Site (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc)